# Is `/dev/shm` universal in Linux and Ubuntu?

Tags: devices, pipe

For FIFO pipe speed I'm considering placing it inside the RAM disk called `/dev/shm`. I see there are some files there already:

```
$ ll /dev/shm
total 1536
drwxrwxrwt  2 root    root         280 Oct  2 17:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x 22 root    root        4840 Oct  2 05:49 ../
-rwx------  1 rick    rick    67108904 Oct  2 04:29 pulse-shm-1087740037*
-rwx------  1 lightdm lightdm 67108904 Oct  2 04:29 pulse-shm-1609193682*
-rwx------  1 rick    rick    67108904 Oct  2 04:34 pulse-shm-2114917541*
-rwx------  1 rick    rick    67108904 Oct  2 04:29 pulse-shm-2616701246*
-rwx------  1 rick    rick    67108904 Oct  2 17:14 pulse-shm-3211887872*
-rwx------  1 rick    rick    67108904 Oct  2 17:14 pulse-shm-3411101615*
-rwx------  1 rick    rick    67108904 Oct  2 04:32 pulse-shm-3740841284*
-rwx------  1 lightdm lightdm 67108904 Oct  2 04:29 pulse-shm-4039050064*
-rwx------  1 rick    rick    67108904 Oct  2 04:29 pulse-shm-608722223*
-rwx------  1 rick    rick    67108904 Oct  2 05:46 pulse-shm-629296834*
-rwx------  1 rick    rick    67108904 Oct  2 17:19 pulse-shm-791566179*
-rwx------  1 lightdm lightdm 67108904 Oct  2 04:29 pulse-shm-871250926*
```

Is it safe to assume this directory is universal on all Ubuntu systems or even better all Linux systems?

If the directory doesn't exist I'll create my pipe FIFO file in `/tmp` but hopefully that never happens.

---

**Edit:** With many thanks to two great answers written below I found this article: [Why use named pipes on Linux](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3251853/linux/why-use-named-pipes-on-linux.html)

> ### Why use named pipes?
>
> Named pipes are used infrequently for a good reason. On Unix systems,
> there are almost always many ways to do pretty much the same thing.
> There are many ways to write to a file, read from a file, and empty a
> file, though named pipes have a certain efficiency going for them.
>
> For one thing, named pipe content resides in memory rather than being
> written to disk. It is passed only when both ends of the pipe have
> been opened. And you can write to a pipe multiple times before it is
> opened at the other end and read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Linux, yes, it is universally available and according to documentation ( https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt )  glibc, the standard C library for Linux expects `/dev/shm` to exist.

However, I'd still suggest reconsidering the design of your script or program. FIFOs and sockets tend to be placed into `/var/run/appname` or `/tmp/` directories. A good example of that is `/var/run/acpid.socket`. Since those filesystems are also tmpfs just like `/dev/shm`, there's no performance difference.

BTW, placing FIFOs  in tmpfs should not affect performance since pipes have hard-coded buffer size of 65536  bytes on Linux but can be changed via  /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size    .  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11954/85039

Answer (score 1):

Data travelling through FIFO special file will never hit the filesystem. This means that whether the underlying filesystem is tmpfs or ext2, the speed of the FIFO should be the same.

`/dev/shm` is intended for use by the POSIX shared memory implementation. For other uses, `/tmp` or `/run` would be more appropriate. If your named pipe is user-specific, using `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` from the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) may be appropriate.

Comment: Fascinating read thank you. I should point out the user is root started by /etc/cron.d and three processes write FIFO from `/etc/systemd/system-sleep`, `/etc/acpi/lid/events` and `dbus-monitor` color management doing a query on `xrandr` find profile. Only one bash script reads from FIFO sorting granular time stamps recorded in epoch seconds + milliseconds. All four programs run as root, although one fakes user XAUTHORITY after signon.

Comment: That sounds like something that is tied to a user login session, so would be better started by the systemd user instance (see `systemd-system.conf(5)`)

Comment: I'll look at `systemd` for the next version. The program called by cron.d is awkward waiting for a primary user to sign in. Thanks for the advice.